# How to convert NSArray to NSString in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdata

I have some java server-side code that creates a string (e.g. `Hello world`) and then converts this string to a byte array, and finally sends to an iOs client.

My iOs client uses `NSStream` to read the data and get the array. 
Now I want to obtain the original string out from the array.

How can I do that?

I have tried converting the array to `NSData` and then to `NSString`, but it fails.
I also tried to convert the array to a string, but it seems to convert the numbers in the array to be a string number instead of my expected string 'Hello world'.

Comment: What does the data look like? Please post the code that you have already tried.

Comment: `My ios client use NSStream to read the data, and got the array` you should get `NSData` if you post bytes.

Comment: server respond a pong message json format: {"type":"PONG","content":[52,55,56,55,55,51,48,51,53]}, and of course this json will be convert to bytes array to send to ios client.  Use code:   uint8_t dataArr[len];
    [_inputStream read:dataArr maxLength:len];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataArr length:len];  to get the data, and use json serialize to get the type is 'PONG', and the content is a array.Now I want to convert the array to be a string.

Comment: @trojanfoe json parsing works fine, and get the value of key 'content' is a array, now I just want to convert the array to origin string. I think it is just like bytes array to string in java.I am an ios developer newbie,don't know how to handle this with OC.

Comment: Why don't you send the string as a UTF8 encoded string?

Comment: You should change your JSON to be like this: `{"type":"PONG","content":"478773035"]}` instead.

Comment: Print out the complete source code of your application. Take all the paper and roll it up to create a really hard paper roll. Walk to the developers who are returning that data and whack them over the head with your hard paper roll. They must have worked hard to make your life hard.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your JSON to be like this: `{"type":"PONG","content":"478773035"]}` instead.

However, something like this would probably work:

```
uint8_t * const buffer = (uint8_t*)calloc( 1, [ bytes count ] + 1 )
assert( buffer ) ;

size_t index = 0 ;
for (NSNumber * byteNumber in bytes)
{
    buffer[ index ] = (uint8_t)[ byteNumber unsignedCharValue ] ;
    ++index;
}

NSString * const string = [ NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer ];

free( (void*)buffer );
```

Comment: What is the type of your 'bytes'? I use [dictionary objectForKey:@"content"] get the value is NSArray.

Comment: it's `NSArray *`. But again, why send your string as a byte array vs a string?

Comment: Server has been running for a long time, web browsers and android client works fine, I just do the ios client development, so I have to follow server rules.

Comment: To be safe, ask the server guys what encoding they are using. The may only be sending ASCII, but I wouldn't be surprised if the idiots use something like Windows1252. Which iOS can handle easily if you tell it, but not if you tell it that the string is UTF8.